# Pinterest Developper API v3 App Still pending

Tags: api, rest, pinterest

Hi I have sent a request for creating new Pinterest App 2 months ago and my app is still pending and Pinterest never has replied to my questions.
Do you have any information that could help me to accelerate my app validation ?
Did I do something wrong ?